# Finding the summary of a simulation (i.e. mean, median, mode, se, etc.), and the distribution of that simulation in R

Tags: r

I have a question, I generated a simulation where you essentially have a 100x100 plot in R and start in the center (50,50), then take a step in one direction and step by step try to reach the outside.

I was able to generate the loop to be able to do this, but now I would like to run this particular loop 10,000 times and then generate a summary for it and look at the distribution.  I'm just not real sure how to run the loop 10,000 times then generate the summary for it or how that might look. I have included what I have so far:

```
plot(0:100,0:100,type="n")
points(50,50,col="red",pch=16,cex=1.5)
x0<-50
y0<-50
x1<-sample(c(-1,0,1),1)
y1<-sample(c(-1,0,1),1)


for(i in 1:50000){
  x1<-sample(c(-1,0,1),1)
  y1<-sample(c(-1,0,1),1)
  lines(c(x0,x0+1),c(y0,y0+1))
  x0<-x0+x1
  y0<-y0+y1
  if(x0>100|x0<0|y0>100|y0<0)break
}
```

Comment: "then generate a summary for it and look at the distribution" - distribution of what exactly are you trying to analyze? I suspect it's the length of the path when it reaches the outside?

Comment: also, shouldn't it be `lines(c(x0,x0+x1),c(y0,y0+y1))` ?

Comment: @IaroslavDomin Or maybe the number of iterations until it goes out of the plot area?

Comment: @RuiBarradas good point, I thought of it as the same thing, but it's not

Comment: @IaroslavDomin well i'm trying to run this loop 10,000 times then take that data (i.e. how many 'steps' it took to reach the side each time) and find the summary like the average number of steps it took out of the 10,000 runs of the loop. Then look at the distribution of those runs and see if its normal or uniform etc

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing we really want to know about a simulation is how many steps it took to reach the outside, we'll start with creating a function which simulates a path and returns only the number of steps.

```r
random_path_length <- function() {
  x <- 50
  y <- 50
  res <- 0
  while (x >= 0 & x <= 100 & y >= 0 & x <= 100) {
    dx <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 1)
    dy <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 1)
    x <- x + dx
    y <- y + dy
    res <- res + 1
  }
  res
}

set.seed(1)
random_path_length()
#> [1] 3210
```

Theoretically we could've used this function then to simulate 10000 results, but the problem is that it takes way to much time. What I propose is to simulate steps not one-by-one but rather in batches to make use of vectorized operations.

```r
random_path_length <- function(batch_size = 1000) {
  x <- 50
  y <- 50
  res <- 0
  go <- TRUE
  while (go) {
    # simulate batch_size number of steps
    dx <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), batch_size, replace = TRUE)
    dy <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), batch_size, replace = TRUE)
    new_x <- x + cumsum(dx)
    new_y <- y + cumsum(dy)
    # stop path at the point when (if) it reaches the outside
    where_reaches <- which(new_x == 0 | new_x == 100 | new_y == 0 | new_y == 100)
    # this batch didn't reach the outside
    if (length(where_reaches) == 0) {
      res <- res + batch_size
      x <- new_x[[batch_size]]
      y <- new_y[[batch_size]]
    } else {
      where_stop <- where_reaches[[1]]
      res <- res + where_stop
      x <- new_x[[where_stop]]
      y <- new_y[[where_stop]]
      go <- FALSE
    }
  }
  res
}

set.seed(1)
random_path_length()
#> [1] 3023
```

Here `batch_size` parameter regulates how many steps we generate at time. You can play with it to find out which works faster.

Having this function we can simulate 10000 results in an acceptable amount of time, and move on with calculating whatever statistics we want.

```r
set.seed(1)
res <- replicate(10000, random_path_length())
summary(res)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>     229    1110    1784    2210    2858   12731

hist(res)
```

[image]

Comment: This is incredible, but do you by chance know how I would be able to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the simulation? Would I be able to do so just using the Walk object and a simple function? Thanks in advance

Comment: @HaleyAbrems `t.test(res)$conf.int` ? It depends actually on what type of interval do you need, this one is for mean. In any case it's easily googleable.

Comment: It's obviously not a normal distribution for a variety of reasons. Also not indicated is whether the CI is supposed to be around an effort at prediction or around a measure of  location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following function is what the question is asking for.

```
simFun <- function(x0 = 50L, y0 = 50L, R = 50000){
  x1 <- sample(c(-1L, 0L, 1L), 1)
  y1 <- sample(c(-1L, 0L, 1L), 1)
  d <- dx <- dy <- 0L
  for(i in seq_len(R)){
    x1 <- sample(c(-1L, 0L, 1L), 1)
    y1 <- sample(c(-1L, 0L, 1L), 1)
    x0 <- x0 + x1
    y0 <- y0 + y1
    if(x0 > 100L || x0 < 0L || y0 > 100L || y0 < 0L) break
    d <- d + abs(x1) + abs(y1)
    dx <- dx + abs(x1)
    dy <- dy + abs(y1)
  }
  c(iter = i, dist = d, dx = dx, dy = dy)
}

set.seed(1234)
sim <- t(replicate(100, simFun()))

hist(sim[, 1])  # or other columns
```